# jackson: InvalidDefinitionException using [Ljava.lang.Double

Tags: java, data-binding, jackson, fasterxml

I'm using Jackson for mapping the following json into a `Map<String, Class>`:

```
    {
    "keyA": "java.lang.Double",
    "keyB": "[Ljava.lang.Double"
    }
```

But I am getting the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.lang.Class`, problem: [Ljava/lang/Double
```

Refering to [the Java documentation for class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3) the value should be correct.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**
I used "[L" as I want to have the class of an Double[].

Comment: `[Ljava/lang/Double` seems to have extra two characters at the start `[L`. is it a typo??

Comment: I use [L because I want to have a Double[].class at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2), object type must end with a semicolon:

```
ObjectType:
    L ClassName ;
```

Change `keyB` to `[Ljava.lang.Double;`:

```
String jsonInput = "{\n" +
  "    \"keyA\": \"java.lang.Double\",\n" +
  "    \"keyB\": \"[Ljava.lang.Double;\",\n" +
  "    \"keyC\": \"java.lang.Double\"\n" +
  "    }";
TypeReference<HashMap<String, Class>> typeRef
  = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Class>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Class> map = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, typeRef);
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{keyA=class java.lang.Double, keyB=class [Ljava.lang.Double;, keyC=class java.lang.Double}
```